# Nginx proxy: How do I configure nginx so that Jersey 2 (JAX-RS 2) still can interact with additional URL parts in it properly?

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker, nginx, jersey-2.0

I am trying to solve this problem, but unfortunately I can't figure it out.

**What am I trying?**

I am trying to redirect a location to a Jersey 2 (JAX-RS 2) Web app which can interact with the requests as usual, but with the difference, that additional parts of the url are in it. 
The Java application with Jersey 2 is running on a tomcat docker image.

---

**Let me try to explain it better like this:**

This is how all my requests have worked:

```
[IP-address]:8888/myJersey2App/something/function
```

Recently I also added SSL, so that my server interacts with https.

Let's say the url for my website is:

> http://my.example.com

So the request would be now like this:

```
https://my.example.com/myJersey2App/something/function
```

**Nginx configuration:**

```
events{
}
http{
    server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name my.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.example.com;

        ###
        # ssl configuration ...
        ###

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }       
    }
}
```

This works, since Jersey 2 still gets, that `/myJersey2App/something/function` is the same path as in the code.

**Web.xml configuration:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myJersey2App/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**This is an example, of how Jersey 2 interacts with requests:**

```
@Path("something")
public class JavaClass {
    @GET
    @Path("/function")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response myFunction() {
        return Response.ok().entity("MyFunction!").build();
    }
```

---

**What do I want?**

Right now, I have to start multiple docker, with the same application, but with a different port **and** url.

This is how it should be requested then:

**Runs on port 7777:**

```
https://my.example.com/docker1/myJersey2App/something/function
```

**Runs on port 8888:**

```
https://my.example.com/docker2/myJersey2App/something/function
```

**Runs on port 9999:**

```
https://my.example.com/docker3/myJersey2App/something/function
```

It is actually the same, but with the difference, that *dockerX* is in the URL.

This is how I thought the Nginx configuration would be:

```
...
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.example.com;

        ###
        # ssl configuration ...
        ###

        location /docker1 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /docker2 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /docker3 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
...
```

Unfortunately, my Jersey2 Application won't recognize the url anymore, since the *dockerX* is inside the url, of course, since **dockerX** is not mentioned in code (which should not be mentioned!)

---

Is it possible to configurate Nginx so that my Jersey application still can recognize it even if the url would look like this:

```
https://my.example.com/docker1/abc/def/ghi/myJersey2App/something/function
```

My Jersey application should still recognize that it only has to start with `/myJersey2App/`

I was thinking of something like "the user sees still the dockerX URL, but in background it is treated like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/myJersey2App/something/function
```

**So, user sees this:**

```
https://my.example.com/docker2/myJersey2App/something/function
```

**But behind it is treated like this:**

```
http://localhost:8888/myJersey2App/something/function
```

Is it possible to configure Nginx, so that it works like this?

I hope you can help me with that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out by myself.

This is how the nginx configuration should be:

```
...
    location /docker1 {

        rewrite /docker1/(.*) /$1  break;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /docker2 {

        rewrite /docker2/(.*) /$1  break;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /docker3 {

        rewrite /docker3/(.*) /$1  break;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
...
```

When you do a request, you still see the **dockerX** part, but behind it is treated as if *dockerX* part doesn't exists, because rewrite removes this part. And well the Jersey Java application can work normally, without changing the actual Jersey 2 application.